# How to manage 'link forwarding' for a website inside a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, webserver

I have a website that uses relative href links (eg. the link directs to "/login", rather than "http://somesite.com/login"). This works A-OK in a normal server but I'd like to use the website inside a docker container as part of a kubernetes cluster. My goal is to have multiple replicas of the website to manage high load times, defaulting to two nodes with dynamic scaling.

I set us the service as a 'loadbalancer' as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websiteservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: websiteapp
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

The issue here is that if I navigate to the URL of the load balancer (that's automatically created at my host - digital ocean) then although the homepage of the website loads, any other pages give me a 404 because rather than loading the "/login" page of the container it loads the "/login" page of the load balancer which doesn't exist. How can I configure my cluster or load balancer to forward all subdirectories (anything after the .com) to the webserver?

**EDIT 1**
In comments I was advised to set up ingress. I *think* I've done so with this change to my yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: somesite.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: websiteservice
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websiteservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: websiteapp
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websiteapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: websiteapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: websiteapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: websiteapp
        image: mydocker.co.uk/websiteimg
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: s-2vcpu-4gb
```

But I'm still not able to navigate beyond the home page of my website.

Comment: Have you tried to setup ingress - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ ?

Comment: You need to setup an ingress controller and manage traffic through it with /* in the path

Answer (score 1):

Your Ingress file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: somesite.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: websiteservice
          servicePort: 80
```

Simply you have add path to redirect traffic.

Take a look: [host-path-routing](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/), [ingress-path-matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/).